# В Laravel 8 как передать аргументы от seed к factory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

### seed

```
public function run(){
    $name = ['John','Artur'];

    User::factory()->count(2)->create(['name' => $name]);
}
```

---

### factory

```
protected $model = User::class;
   
public function definition(){
   return [
       'name' => $name, //тут нужно получить значение
       'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
   ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Делается это через `Sequence` и метод `state` или просто метод `sequence`. Читайте данный [раздел](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing) документации. В вашей фабрике оставьте фейковое имя, если вдруг вы создадите не 2, а 10 пользователей, а входной массив будет состоять из двух значений, то 2 создадутся с вашими именами, а остальные с фейковыми

Примеры:

```
$names = [
    ['name' => 'John'],
    ['name' => 'Arthur']
];
\App\Models\User::factory()->count(2)
     ->sequence(...$names)
     ->create();
```

или

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Sequence;

$names = [
    ['name' => 'John'],
    ['name' => 'Arthur']
];
\App\Models\User::factory()->count(2)
     ->state(new Sequence(...$names))
     ->create();
```